# Rayleigh quotient over sparse vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ Hermitian positive definite matrix. The well-known Rayleigh quotient
\begin{equation}
R(A,z) := \frac{z^*Az}{z^*z},\  (z \neq 0) \in \mathbb{C}^n
\end{equation}
is bounded above and below by the maximum and minumum eigenvalues $\lambda_\mathrm{max}(A)$ and $\lambda_\mathrm{min}(A)$, respectively. Now, however, consider a restriction on $z$ such that they are at most $k$-sparse (in the same basis as $A$), $k<n$. For the purposes of notation, we denote this by the set
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S} := \{z \in \mathbb{C}^n : \, 0 < |\mathrm{supp}(z)| \leq k\}
\end{equation}
In general these vectors will not be eigenvectors of $A$, and so in the interest of non-trivial results, we will explicitly impose that condition. Thus we should expect
\begin{align}
\max_{z\in\mathcal{S}} R(A,z) &< \lambda_\mathrm{max}(A),\\
\min_{z\in\mathcal{S}} R(A,z) &> \lambda_\mathrm{min}(A).
\end{align}

My question is: are there any useful estimates (in the sense that they depend on the sparsity $k$) on the above expressions, assuming we know the spectrum of $A$?

I imagine that there must be a few published results out there about this problem, but I have only found works regarding sparse matrices, rather than vectors. (For what it's worth, I can show a simplistic upper bound, but am rather lost when it comes to the minimum.)

Answer (score 1):

Diagonalizing and writing $A=\sum_i \lambda_i e_i e_i^T$ you have (supposing $z$ of norm 1):
$$ R(A,z)=\sum_i \lambda_i (e_i^T z)^2 $$
so it depends on how well your sparse vector may be aligned with the smallest (or largest) eigenvector. I suppose that you intend to use it on a sparse matrix $A$ but as eigenvectors need not be (even close to) sparse  I don't quite see a situation where the approach will be very useful (but just my opinion).